# C# cannot access file immediately after creating it

Tags: c#, file, race-condition, streamwriter

I have a scenario where I need to check if a txt file exists, if it doesn't I need to create it.

Immediately after this, I need to populate the file with some text.

This is what my code looks like:

```
if (!File.Exists(_filePath))
{
    File.Create(_filePath);
}

using (var streamWriter = File.AppendText(_filePath))
{
    //Write to file
}
```

I receive an exception (`System.IO.IOException`) on line 5, only when a new file has to be created. Here is the exception:

`The process cannot access the file '**redacted file path**' because it is being used by another process.`

I don't want to add something like `Thread.Sleep(1000);`, as that is an awful solution.

Is there a way to find out when the file is free again, so that I can write to it?

Comment: Use `File.Create(_filePath).Close();`. `File.Create()` returns an open file which won't be closed until it's finalizer runs as a side-effect of garbage collection, unless you close it explicitly. But you shouldn't need to create it separately like that.

Comment: Why creating the file? _Creates a StreamWriter that appends UTF-8 encoded text to an existing file, or to a new file if the specified file does not exist._

Comment: You should close the filestream after creation, or write immediately, like in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.7.2) example

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The using-statement will close and dispose the streamwriter.

Comment: `File.Create` creates a file and opens a stream. Either use that stream with `StreamWriter` or use `File.AppendText` without `File.Create`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use StreamWriter with param `append = true`. It'll create the file if needed.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_filePath, true, Encoding.Default))
{
   sw.WriteLine("blablabla");
}
```

Comment: Actually, OP can just use the code they already have - `File.AppendText()` will create the file if it doesn't exist. They just need to remove the `File.Create()` code and all will be fine.

Comment: Matthew Watson, Definitely)

Answer (score 5):

FileCreate method return Filestream which should be closed before using StreamWriter

```
if (!File.Exists(_filePath))
{
// close fileStream
    File.Create(_filePath).Close();
}

using (var streamWriter = File.AppendText(_filePath))
{
    //Write to file
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You were so close, just remove the first `if`, the `File.AppendText` will do the trick for you and create file if not there.

```
using (var streamWriter = File.AppendText(_filePath))
{
    //write to file
}
```